# Week on week evolution

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this :

```
   date_    | my_daily_count      
------------+------------------
 2023-07-18 |              1                        
 2023-07-19 |              0 
 2023-07-20 |              0 
 2023-07-21 |              2 
 2023-07-22 |              0
 2023-07-23 |              0 
 2023-07-24 |              1
 2023-07-25 |              0
 2023-07-26 |              0
 2023-07-27 |              0 
 2023-07-28 |              0
 2023-07-29 |              0
 2023-07-30 |              0
 2023-07-31 |              1
 2023-08-01 |              1
 2023-08-02 |              0
 2023-08-03 |              1 
 2023-08-04 |              0
 2023-08-05 |              0
 2023-08-06 |              0
 2023-08-07 |              0
 2023-08-08 |              0
```

I would like to output from this a week on week summary, i.e a table where in each row I have the Monday date and the sum of `my_daily_count` over the week of this Monday (up to Sunday).

The first week might be incomplete (eg the first row above is a Tuesday), in this case the corresponding output row starts with the first day available of this week (2023-07-18 in the example).

We mark the Monday date of the last week with something if it is incomplete, for example adding a "not complete" after the date

**Desired output:**

[image]

So far, I have been able to sum over weeks, however if the first week is incomplete, then I get the Monday date instead of the date that is available in my input table (I get 2023-07-17 instead of 2023-07-18), and also I don't know how to detect if the last week is complete or not, and mark it accordingly. Here is what I have done:

```
SELECT
       DATE_TRUNC('week', date_)::DATE AS week_,
       SUM(my_daily_count) AS my_weekly_count   
FROM my_table    
GROUP BY week_
ORDER BY week_ ;
```

Comment: What is the output you actually want?

Comment: it's in the screenshot

Comment: Please do not post screen shots, post as formatted text. See [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). A good place to cleanly format text is at [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/). Your screen shot is basically unreadable.